# Does an American need to fill out W9 if paid in Euro to his European bank by a US co.?

Tags: usa, us-citizens

I am a US citizen living abroad in Europe.  No longer a US resident, I file taxes with a 2555 foreign earned income exemption and pay all taxes and social security in the country of residence--which has both tax treaties and totalization agreements with the US.

If I consult for a US company, can they pay me in European Euros directly to my european bank account and, if so, do I need to fill out a W9 form?

My main source of income is in Euro, being employed by a European company, in Europe where I reside. Although I am still, and only, an American citizen. The US consult is short-term temporary work; I prefer they pay me in Euros directly to my European bank account.

Comment: If you are a US citizen you have a SSN.  Why would you need another Tax ID?

Comment: My question still stands.  Why do you need to have another Tax ID for the IRS if you already have one?  Whether or not you're paid in Europe and in Euros is irrelevant.  If you're looking to set up a company then it's different story altogether.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I’m not understanding the purpose of a W9. I had understood that taxpayers must fill them out when they are working as a freelancer rather than as an employee, its purpose to declare the sum being earned as freelancer. I didn’t realize its purpose was to request a TIN. Thanks for your help, and your time!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fill it out for the European Bank but to [provide them with your SSN](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) as part of the FATCA reporting.  So yes you will need to fill one out but not because you're paid in Euro but because you have an account in a European Bank.